# File IO on Main Thread with Evergage

Tags: marketing-cloud, evergage

I have connected Sentry to my app which gives me the following error:
File IO on Main Thread - file.write - Evergage-config (578 B) with the following call stack:

```
[
    {
        "filename": "AppCompatActivity.java",
        "function": "onStop",
        "lineno": 1,
        "module": "o2.c",
        "native": false
    },
    {
        "filename": "FragmentActivity.java",
        "function": "onStop",
        "lineno": 1,
        "module": "androidx.fragment.app.n",
        "native": false
    },
    {
        "filename": "AppLifecycleManager.java",
        "function": "onActivityStopped",
        "lineno": 49,
        "module": "com.evergage.android.internal.AppLifecycleManager",
        "native": false
    },
    {
        "filename": "AppLifecycleManager.java",
        "function": "confirmBg",
        "lineno": 42,
        "module": "com.evergage.android.internal.AppLifecycleManager",
        "native": false
    },
    {
        "filename": "AppLifecycleManager.java",
        "function": "recalculateState",
        "lineno": 65,
        "module": "com.evergage.android.internal.AppLifecycleManager",
        "native": false
    },
    {
        "filename": "EvergageImpl.java",
        "function": "onAppStateChange",
        "lineno": 3,
        "module": "com.evergage.android.internal.EvergageImpl$1",
        "native": false
    },
    {
        "filename": "EvergageImpl.java",
        "function": "access$000",
        "lineno": 1,
        "module": "com.evergage.android.internal.EvergageImpl",
        "native": false
    },
    {
        "filename": "EvergageImpl.java",
        "function": "onAppStateChange",
        "lineno": 155,
        "module": "com.evergage.android.internal.EvergageImpl",
        "native": false
    },
    {
        "filename": "EvergageImpl.java",
        "function": "stopSystemsAsNecessary",
        "lineno": 59,
        "module": "com.evergage.android.internal.EvergageImpl",
        "native": false
    },
    {
        "filename": "QueuedEventSender.java",
        "function": "saveToFile",
        "lineno": 12,
        "module": "com.evergage.android.internal.QueuedEventSender",
        "native": false
    },
    {
        "filename": "Persistence.java",
        "function": "saveRawJSONToFile",
        "lineno": 91,
        "module": "com.evergage.android.internal.util.Persistence",
        "native": false
    },
    {
        "filename": "SafetyUtil.java",
        "function": "closeSafely",
        "lineno": 4,
        "module": "com.evergage.android.internal.util.SafetyUtil",
        "native": false
    }
]
```

And indeed it is writing to file on the main thread:

```
    @MainThread
    void saveToFile() {
        SafetyUtil.assertOnMain();
        String jsonString = this.eventQueue.toString();
        Persistence.saveRawJSONToFile("Evergage-events", jsonString);
    }
```

```
    public static void saveRawJSONToFile(@NonNull String fileName, @NonNull String json) {
        String filesDir;
        if (StringUtil.isValid(fileName) && StringUtil.isValid(json) && StringUtil.isValid(filesDir = getFilesDir())) {
            File folder = new File(filesDir);
            if (!folder.exists() && !folder.mkdir()) {
                Logger.log(1000, "Persistence", (Throwable)null, new String[]{"Unable to create files dir: ", filesDir});
            } else {
                String filePath = getFilePath(filesDir, fileName);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
                FileLock fileLock = null;

                try {
                    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
                    fileOutputStream.write(json.getBytes(Constants.CHARSET_UTF_8));
                    fileOutputStream.flush();
                    fileOutputStream.getFD().sync();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException var18) {
                    Logger.log(1000, "Persistence", var18, new String[]{"Couldn't find files dir: ", filePath});
                } catch (Exception var19) {
                    Logger.log(1000, "Persistence", var19, new String[]{"Error writing to file: ", filePath});
                } finally {
                    SafetyUtil.closeSafely(fileOutputStream, true);

                    try {
                        if (fileLock != null) {
                            ((FileLock)fileLock).release();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception var17) {
                        Logger.log(2000, "Persistence", var17, new String[]{"Error releasing file lock"});
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to prevent this? Is this a bug? if it a bug where can I report it? I have been trying to find the right place for it with no success.